# URL request in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an URL request in Javascript. The response to the request is in plain text. In a shell script I could do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

x=$(wget -O- "http://www.example.com/give_cookie?token=85EFC743VGDSX534DWDSACVC")

echo "$x"
```

This would be the result of running the script:

```
$ response( {"name":"user4015668","message":"OM_NOM_NOM_THANKS_FOR_COOKIE"} );
```

First I looked at XMLHttpRequest, but found out that it would not work as the request is to another domain. I then read about this method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My website</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.createElement('script');
  x.src = http://www.example.com/give_cookie?token=85EFC743VGDSX534DWDSACVC
  document.head.appendChild(x);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When loading the page in Firefox while using Firebug i see this in the `<head>` section under the HTML fane:

```
[-] <script src="http://www.example.com/give_cookie?token=85EFC743VGDSX534DWDSACVC">
       1  response( {"name":"user4015668","message":"OM_NOM_NOM_THANKS_FOR_COOKIE"} );
```

The response now seem to be somewhere in the HTML document, but I don't know how I can get in touch with it.

Can I somehow direct the response to a variable, like in my shell script example?

Comment: No.  You cannot do synchronous network IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First I looked at XMLHttpRequest, but found out that it would not work as the request is to another domain.

Exactly, you cannot use XHR to retrieve content from another domain [without that other domain's active participation through CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The request data you show however is in JSONP format. That means it can indeed be loaded with a `<script>` tag, because the return value is valid Javascript. If you read what is in the response, you see that it calls the `response` function with the object as its only parameter. Therefore you need to define one, for example:

```
function response(v) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

[Read more on JSONP here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Usually a JSONP-supporting server allows you to specify the function name in its response through a GET-parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can see this response in the console log: `Object { name="user4015668", message="OM_NOM_NOM_THANKS_FOR_COOKIE"}` I would then expect that I could do something like: `alert(v)` and have the response shown in a popup, but the text shown is `[object Object]` Do you know how I can get the correct response?

Comment: I will answer that myself: `alert(v.name);` and `alert(v.message);`